# How can I automatically connect to a WPA/WPA2 Enterprise without having the CA certificate beforehand?

Tags: networking, network-manager, wpa2, wpa

My school has a WPA/WPA2 Enterprise network. It has a CA certificate, which on my iPhone I am prompted to trust, while on my Macbook it was automatically trusted when I entered my username and password (if I recall correctly). I have a new laptop with Ubuntu on it, and upon attempting to connect to the network, I am prompted with authentication type and various other options depending on which authentication type I choose.

WPA/WPA2 Enterprise authentication screen:

[image: WPA/WPA2 Enterprise authentication screen]

I don't know which authentication type it uses and I don't know what to put in any of the subsequent fields. However, I know there must be some way to find out, because I'm not asked for it on any other device. I did some trial and error and discovered that choosing "Protected EAP (PEAP)", ticking "no certificate is required", and entering my username and password will allow me to connect to the internet, albeit with an SSL certificate error thrown at every turn.

I looked at the certificate information that was shown to me on my iPhone and saw a few URLs with a domain that only resolved when I was connected to the school wifi under the `CRL Distribution Points` and `Certificate Authority Information Access` headings. I'm happy to provide more information about this but I'm not sure how much of it should be kept private. This domain was talking about certificates and had some links to some `.crl`s and `.crt`s, as well as a static HTML page talking about and linking to some `.cer`s. Two files were named specifically on the certificate information page on my phone - both with the same name, but one with a `.crl` and the other with a `.crt` extension (in the `CRL Distribution Points` and `Certificate Authority Information Access` sections respectively). I checked and it turns out that both of those files exist and can be downloaded, although they had different casing in the directory list on the page. I tried using the `crt` for the certificate when connecting with PEAP, but it didn't connect - just kept asking for the password. I then tried another certificate which the webpage described as "the new root certificate" (in contrast to the "existing legacy root certificate", which was also linked), and while it allowed me to successfully connect to the network, I was still getting all the same SSL errors as when I wasn't using a certificate at all.

I've looked at several AskUbuntu questions, but most of them are either outdated advice (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1), are asking about networks which do not require a certificate, or are being told to ask the IT support at school for the certificate file. While the latter could be an option, it is definitely not necessary as no other devices that I have tested require manually entering a certificate file, which means there must be some way for them (and therefore myself) to figure out where to get it.

In an attempt to avoid an XY problem, I have two possible questions. I either want to know:

> How do I connect to a certificate-requiring but otherwise unknown WPA/WPA2 Enterprise network with only a username and password on Ubuntu

or

> How do I find out which authentication type a WPA/WPA2 Enterprise network is using, as well as the further relevant information including the certificate file?

Comment: The second part of the question is easy. Ask the school IT dept.

Comment: @David Sure, but I'm trying to avoid that, because I know it's possible to find out without asking. I guess a better question would be `How do other OSs find out which authentication type a WPA/WPA2 Enterprise network is using, as well as the further relevant information including the certificate file when connecting to it, and how do I replicate that process on Ubuntu, either automatically or manually?`